# Metalkit: MTLBuffer and pointers in swift 3

Tags: pointers, memory-management, swift3, metalkit

I started with Metalkit and I have a very simple kernel as a test case.

```
kernel void compute(device float* outData [[ buffer(0) ]])
{
  outData[0] = 234.5;
  outData[3] = 345.6;
}
```

This "computed" data is stored in a `MTLBuffer`.

```
var buffer : MTLBuffer?
...
buffer = device.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 5, options: [])
...
commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
```

At this point the kernel has written some test data to the `MTLBuffer`.
Question is how I should access that data from my main program?

I get a `unsafeMutableRawPointer` from `buffer.contents()`. How do I get a swift array of values that I can use everywhere else (displaying on screen, writing to file,...)?

These snippets work in this very simple app, but I am not sure if they are correct:

```
let raw = buffer.contents()
let b = raw.bindMemory(to: Float.self, capacity: 5) 
print(b.advanced(by: 3).pointee)

let a = raw.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self)
print(a.advanced(by: 3).pointee)


let bufferPointer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: b, count: 5)
let values = Array(bufferPointer)
print(values)


let value = raw.load(fromByteOffset: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 3, as: Float.self)
print(value)
```

Both `bindMemory` and `assumingMemoryBound` work. Though `assumingMemoryBound` assumes the underlying bytes are already typed and `bindMemory` doesn't. I think that one of either should work, but not both. Which one should it be and why?

Answer (score 1):

I use the code presented below to load to arrays, but I can't decide if mine or your version is best.

```
let count = 16

var array = [Float]()
array.reserveCapacity(count)

    for i in 0..<count {
        array.append(buffer.contents().load(fromByteOffset: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * i, as: Float.self))
    }
```

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at this, so I (still) don't know what the answer should be. Having said that, your version copies the data byte by byte. Copying bytes just to get it into another container is a red flag for me. Is it really necessary to do a copy?

Comment: @user965972 As far as I know, this is the only way to do it, but I haven't looked at the `UnsafeBufferPointer`. I'm neither very skilled at low level, but I thought I at least could give a temporary solution. If I'm right, you can share memory between the CPU and GPU, so there might be a better way to load data from an MTLBuffer.